# Как при методе map получается undifined?

Tags: javascript

```
const items = [{ price: -50 }, { price: 50 }, { price: '100' }, { price: 100 }];

let result = items.map(({ price }) => {
  price;
  if (price > 0) console.log(price);
});

console.log(result);
```

> 50 100 100 [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

Почему при выводе появляется еще и массив  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ] , откуда и почему он выводиться ? Как его убрать можно ?

Answer (score 2):

callback-функция в `map` должна что-то возвращать. Т.к. принудительно ничего не указано (не прописан `return`), то **по умолчанию функция всегда** возвращает `undefined`. В итоге map пробегается по 4-ём элементам и под капотом складывает 4 `undefined` в массив, который в итоге и возвращается в виде `result` (`map`, напомню, возвращает массив ровно по тому количеству элементов, сколько было на входе)

---

> Как его убрать можно ?

Как минимум возвращать значения.

А вообще, может тут и не нужен `map`? Зависит от того, какая задача решается и какой результат ожидается.